# How does consts work for declarations in C?

Tags: c

I can't seem to find the difference between putting `const` before and/or after the type. why am I allowed to be absurd when it comes to putting `const` everywhere?

```
void test1(const int v)
void test1(int const v)
void test1(const int const v)
void test1(const const int const const v)
void test1(const const const const const const const int v)
```

But frankly, this is kind of silly. Why is this allowed? I feel like it should be a compiler error if 1 or more modifier is applied to the same type. Is there a difference between all of this?

Comment: No, there's no difference.

Comment: you could also do: ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; in C =)

Comment: Don’t overlook `long const int static long x;`.

Comment: Using `const` with non-pointers does not buy you much.  Using `const` with pointers means that `int const *x` and `int *const y` are different; and `char const * const * const p;` is a possibility.  Removing different occurrences of `const` from that declaration of `p` changes the type significantly.  Note too that the standard [§6.7.3 Type qualifiers ¶5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3p5) says: _If the same qualifier appears more than once in the same specifier-qualifier-list, either directly or via one or more typedefs, the behavior is the same as if it appeared only once._

Comment: Whenever you have a question *"Why is this nonsense allowed in C?"* answer is usually *"It sucks, but we are keeping it in the name of backwards compatibility"* or *"this hasn't caused enough problems for anybody to try to fix it"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference, sometimes this must be allowed by compiler checks, because you could have const typedefs:

```
typedef const uint32_t cuint32_t;
```

and if people do:

```
const cuint32_t c;
```

there should be no error.

Regarding pointers there is a difference:

```
uint32_t* const a; //declares a constant pointer-variable
```

is different from:

```
 const uint32_t* a; //declares the content pointed at constant
```